# Suppress/remove carriage return from awk output

Tags: awk

I have a simple command to return the uptime/load average from a list of servers, and am using awk to format the output:

`for i in $(cat servers); do ssh $i -qt "uptime" | awk -F\, -v host=\"$i\" '{ print host, $4, $5, $6 }'; done`

This works reasonably well:

```
"server1"   load average: 0.22  0.37  1.99
"server2"   load average: 0.22  0.37  1.99
"server3"   load average: 5.96  4.39  5.66
```

Unfortunately, the last field must contain a carriage return, meaning it can't appear anywhere but the end of the command. For example:

`for i in $(cat servers); do ssh $i -qt "uptime" | awk -F\, -v host=\"$i\" '{ print host, $6, $5, $4 }'; done`

Output:

```
0.64   load average: 0.17"  1.74
0.64   load average: 0.17"  1.74
0.78   load average: 0.15"  3.24
```

How can I remove the carriage return from either a) the end of the input, or b) the end of field $6?

Comment: try removing the  `-t` option from `ssh`

Comment: This worked. Add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should remove the `-t` option from `ssh` in order to prevent generating the carriage return in the first place.

The `-t` option directs ssh to allocate a pseudo terminal on the *remote* machine, and if that terminal has the `onlcr` flag set (which is the default), every LF (`\n`) will be translated to CR/LF (`\r\n`) on output. The `-t` option is not needed unless a full-screen and/or interactive program is run, like `vi` or `screen`.

But if you really have to process lines terminated by CR/LF in `awk`, you can set the record separator to CR/LF in any awk implementation which supports multi-character/regex record separators -- like gawk or mawk. Example:

```
awk ... 'BEGIN{RS="\r\n"}{...}'
```

Also, if you want to remove a stray CR from a field in `awk`, you can use `sub` or `gsub` (which works everywhere):

```
gsub("\r","",$6)
```

Comment: Thank you!  I needed that `gsub()` for the output I was getting from `curl`

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the trailing `\r` with sed

```
ssh $i -qt "uptime" | sed 's/\r$//' | awk ...
# ....................^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Additionally, for best practice, [don't read lines from a file with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried rewriting the command to use while, but it doesn't work. Can you help? Command is 
while IFS= read -r i; do ssh $i -q "uptime" | awk -F\, -v host=\"$i\" '{ print host, $6, $5, $4 }'; done < servers

Comment: You need to modify the data *between* its creation (ssh uptime) and its consumption (awk). How does a while loop help with that?

Comment: I don't know, I was following the instructions in your link. The original question was resolved by removing -t from the ssh command.

Answer (score 0):

I see the answer that suggests to use "sed"
I suggest to use "tr" as an alternative

```
$ awk '{print $1}' < /proc/loadavg  | tr '\n' ' '
```

or

```
$ awk '{print $1}' < /proc/loadavg  | tr -d '\n'
```